# Get 24-hours format

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-date, date

I am converting `timestamp` to `Solar Hijri` and good work like bellow :

```
    private String getDate(long timestamp) {
        Date date = new Date(timestamp * 1000L);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd/HH:mm", Locale.UK);
        String[] paths = sdf.format(date).split("/");
        CalendarTool ct = new CalendarTool(Integer.parseInt(paths[0]),
                Integer.parseInt(paths[1]),
                Integer.parseInt(paths[2]));
        return ct.getIranianDate().trim() + " - " + paths[3].trim();
    }
```

**Problem:** I get time base 24 hours but when I have 12:45 or 24:13 show me 00:45 and 00:13 always, but I need to  12:45 and 00:13.

I have problem with 12 and 00 .

For example my `timestamp` is : 1515186060

Comment: @ Noise Generator . Sorry 00:13 .

Comment: This format looks very weird to me: `"yyyy/MM/dd/HH:mm"` You normally use the ISO standard `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm"`. Or one of its variants (with/out seconds and/or timezone).

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Your `sdf` gives me 12:45 and 00:13, exactly as you said you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **kk** to do that

```
simpDate = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");
```

If you use **kk** you will get results like 24:30 but if you use **HH** you can get it like 00:30.
Or simply create the instance of Calendar and get 24 hr time by,

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

int Hr24 = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int Min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Comment: Just get me 24 always .

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `kk` do that for you. anyway .... check the new way also @JoJoRoid